# Load value of a table based on previously stored value in the session on back button click

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have a table that has the following columns:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th st-sort="Check">Check</th>
<th st-sort="partNo">Part No.</th>
<th st-sort="quantity">Quantity</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr st-select-row="part" ng-repeat="part in vm.parts">
<td><input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" name="mycheckbox" ng-model="mycheckbox" data-ng-change="getQuantity(text) ; mycheckbox ? addPart(part) : deleteItem($index,part)" value="{{part.partNo}}" check-list='checked_parts'></td>
<td>{{part.partNo}}</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="text" id="ng-change-text"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

when i click next button i save the quantities and the checked parts in an array in a service and get back both on load after back button click

Problem:
when i click the back button from previous page i want to check the checkboxes corresponding to saved parts and also display the quantity in the textbox,
how to achieve this?

[how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzdPE.png)
[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts1DT.png)

Comment: Your "part" array should be loaded from service . Then the data would be persisted across pages. Please setup a plunker/fiddle if you need help with the code.

Comment: @VijayMenon the vm.parts is an array of all parts that is being loaded , i want the parts selected before to be checked while displaying all the parts. i have added images . i have the checked parts in the service i just dont know how to compare.

Comment: I saw the images, but as mentioned before, need to see the data and JS code to assist further.